# Is there a way to populate a TextField in a drop-down manner in SwiftUI?

Tags: drop-down-menu, alamofire, swiftui, textfield, populate

I would like to populate some TextFields in my SwiftUI application with pre-populated options using the data from my AlamoFire .post request methods.

Is this possible?

Cheers,
Oliver

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this as I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you are looking for then here is how you achieve this.

[image: Auto complete text view]

```
//
//  SellerbuddyAutoCompleteView.swift
//  iosApp
//
//  Created by Vikas on 21/08/21.
//  Copyright © 2021 orgName. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI


struct SellerbuddyAutoCompleteView: View {
    
    var errorMsg: String = ""
    var isDisabled: Bool = false
    @Binding var text: String
    let hint : String
    @Binding var isValid: Bool
    @State var hasOptions : Bool
    @State var options: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            TextField(LocalizedStringKey(hint), text: $text)
                .padding(.all, 12)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).stroke(getEditTextColor(isValid), lineWidth: 1)
                ).overlay(
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        if hasOptions {
                            
                            Spacer().frame(height: 50)
                            
                            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                                
                                ForEach(options, id: \.self) {
                                    Text($0).frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(8)
                                    Divider()
                                }
                                
                            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6).foregroundColor(.white).shadow(radius: 4))
                            
                        }
                        
                    }.offset(y: 50)
                    
                    , alignment: .topLeading)
                .overlay(
                    
                    Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.down.circle.fill").resizable().frame(width: 20, height: 20).padding().onTapGesture {
                        
                        self.hasOptions = false
                        
                    }
                    
                    , alignment: .trailing)
            
            
            
            Text(errorMsg)
                .visibility(hidden: $isValid).padding(.leading, 4)
                .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                .offset(y: -5)
                .frame(height: isValid ? 0: 10)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            
        }.padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 8).frame(height: 45)
    }
    
    func getEditTextColor(_ isValid: Bool) -> Color {
        if !isValid {
            return Color.red
        }else if isDisabled {
            return Color.gray
        } else {
            return Color.blue
        }
    }
}

struct SellerbuddyAutoCompleteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var options = [String](arrayLiteral: "Afghanistan","America")
    static var previews: some View {
        SellerbuddyAutoCompleteView(errorMsg : "Some error has happened",text: Binding.constant("Search countries here"), hint: "signin_hint_email_id", isValid: Binding.constant(true), hasOptions: (true), options: options)
    }
    
}
```

Above shows the code just for the custom view you need to call this view from some swiftui view to enable with all the data mentioned in the view. Do make other changes like ui and color and font etc as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking and the answer is yes. The simplest way is to create a dedicated TextField view outside of the default ContentView.

```
struct MyAlamoFireText: View {
  @State var someText = ""
  var body: some View {
    TestField("Default prompt", text: $someText)
  }
}
struct ContextView: View {
  var body: some View {
    MyAlamoFireText(someText: "Initial value of text")
  }
}
```

Basically what you need is one level of indirection and that will set what text is initially displayed in the field. How you get the data you need to pass into it will depend on your architecture.

Comment: I think the original poster meant a popup menu appears under the TextField with suggestions based on what the user typed so far.